# bad dump specification

Tags: oracle, impdp

when trying to import a database to a local machine I get this error:

```
[oracle@9250f1edf0c7 /]$ impdp user/pass dumpfile=EXPDPDAT-OWNER.dmp directory=dpump_dir1 content=ALL REMAP_TABLESPACE=INDEX:DATA Parallel=8

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Apr 14 21:31:07 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "/tms/import/EXPDPDAT-OWNER.dmp" for read
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. The file does not exist or can not be read due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: Does the directory exist on the local machine? Does the `dmp`  file exist on the local machine in that directory? Does the `oracle` user (or the user that is doing the import) have access to that directory? Please [edit] your question and add missing details. Welcome to DBA.SE. You might want to have a look at [ask] to increase the quality of and responses to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing into a RAC database? If so, the worker processes might be started on all nodes, so either ensure that the directory and dump file is available on all nodes or use CLUSTER=N to force all workers on to the same node.